# as one variable increases another decreases

Tags: algorithm

I have 2 variables.

`float Speed;`

`float SteeringAngle;`

My speed value currently increases. What I want to do is reduce the steering angle as speed increases. It should be a simple equation but I can't seem to work it out.

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this will work as the speed can be 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious approach would be something like:

```
Speed = factor / steeringAngle;
```

Edit: oops -- I misread your request. If you want to reduce the steering angle as the speed increases, you'd want something like:

```
if (speed > 0)
    steeringAngle -= factor / speed;
```

Comment: Rearranging this to give steeringAngle would be
`steeringAngle = factor/speed`
This would mean a divide by 0 may occur I think.

Comment: Thank you for this. Got it working now cheers. I had to add another if statement to stop the steering angle becoming negative
`if (steeringAngle_ < 0)`
`steeringAngle_ *= -1;`

Answer (score 1):

You could try this formula:

- factor - a number in the range 1..N which is used to scale down the steering angle.
- maxSpeed - the value of the expected maximum speed at which the maximum factor is applied to reduce the steering angle.
- requestedAngle - the currently required steering angle

.

```
float factor;
float maxSpeed;
float requestedAngle;
float Speed;

float SteeringAngle = requestedAngle/( (Speed * factor / maxSpeed) + 1);
```

There are many possible formulas.

I would suggest you try to plot graphs of speeds and angles